# Exporting large txt file as point shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, text, big-data

I have a large txt file with 10 million rows and 16 columns and I already have imported the table as a delimited text file in QGIS. In row 7 and row 8, the coordinates are stored (I also allocated x and y to these coordinates).

In QGIS, the attribute table is displayed in the right format and all information is in place. However, if I want to export the table as a point shapefile, it shows (and exports) only the headers, but with no content (no attributes).

Do you have any ideas, why this happens? I am using QGIS 3.16.

Comment: Do the points show up on the map after you imported the txt-file? How long does the export take? Have you tried using e.g. geopackage for export?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. If your sixteen fields exceed 210-220 bytes, it won't be a valid shapefile (too large). Use a different format.

Comment: Have a look a this : https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm to see if you hit some of the attribute limitation of the shapefile format. Also while still less than the theoretical maximum of 70 million point at 10 million row you get close to the usability of shapefile

Answer (score 2):

I guess, I just found the answer for my question. When importing the txt-file, I did not tick the box "Decimal separator is comma" (which is the case for my coordinates).

After doing that, the coordinates are displayed as points on the map and the export works fine.

Did not know the limitations of shapefiles.

If necessary, you can delete or close my question, because so far, I do not know how to do this (but will definitely do the tour after work).